# How can i convert string to Hex data?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am confused to convert string to hex data.
https://gist.github.com/tauzen/3d18825ae41ff3fc8981
I have code in swift language.

```
func stringToBytes(hexstring: String) -> Data? {
    var data = Data(capacity: hexstring.characters.count / 2)

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
    regex.enumerateMatches(in: hexstring, range: NSMakeRange(0, hexstring.utf16.count)) { match, flags, stop in
        let byteString = (hexstring as NSString).substring(with: match!.range)
        var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)!
        data.append(&num, count: 1)
    }

    guard data.count > 0 else { return nil }

    return data
}
```

Comment: Where are your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am not familiar with this language, but I would suggest iterating over the length of your input / hex string in pairs of characters to convert them to a byte. The regex approach doesnt seem right.